# jQuery autocomplete with asmx issue

Tags: jquery, web-services, autocomplete

I am having a strange issue. I am trying to use jQuery autocomplete with asmx web service. My JavaScript code is as:

```
$('#txtUsers').autocomplete('AjaxHandler.asmx/GetUserData', {
    width: 320,
    max: 5,
    minChars: 3,
    parse: function(data) {
        var items = data.d;
        var parsed = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
            parsed.push({
            data: [items[i]],
            value: items[i],
            result: [items[i]]
        });
        return parsed;
    }
});
```

and my web service code is:

```
[WebService]
[ScriptService]
public class AjaxHandler : WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public List<UserData> GetUserData(string q)
    {
        //My code here.....
    }
}
```

However my web method is not being called from autocomplete. However whenever I try to call the same web method from jQuery.ajax, it gets fired correctly. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I checked that autocomplete send get request, but you service accept only post requests. So, i see that you also found it.**

I suggest to use simple HttpHandler, and return data as json using [newton json serializer](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx), because you web service retun 'wrapped' data.
It should be very simple handler:

```
List<UserData> items = GetUserDataItems();
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items);
```

//retrun json to the client

Also at client code set dataType to json:

```
dataType: "json",
```

And parse like this:

```
parse: function (data) {
    return $.map(data, function (row, i) {
        return {
            data: row,
            value: row,
            result: row
        }
    });
},
```

Comment: My issue is not json data. My issue is the web service method is not getting called from autocomplete where-in it is getting perfectly called from $.ajax.

Comment: You sure that you method wasn't called by aotocomplete? Did you tried debug service when autocomplet work? Seems problem because autocomplete can't parse data. But it just suggestion it may be wrong.

Comment: Just try to send json it's simple and i am sure that it will be work.

Comment: Yes. I had put a breakpoint in my server side code which is not getting hit with autocomplete. However it is working with aspx page. but if my aspx why not by asmx?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I've stand with this problem also. Neither ScriptService nor ScriptMethod helps for autocomplete. The simplest work around is convert your **.asmx** into **.ashx** and manage return result as it is expected by AJAX plugin with help of JSON serializer.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. However issue was resolved by including

<configuration>  
    <system.web>  
    <webServices>  
        <protocols>  
            <add name="HttpGet"/>  
            <add name="HttpPost"/>  
        </protocols>  
    </webServices>  
    </system.web>  
</configuration>

in web.config